# add callback to function(e) Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a function which I can not seem to add callback into.

```
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e) {
  someotherfunctionsinside();
  if (e)...
});

function test () {
    console.log('abraka');

}
```

I try do do

```
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, callback) {
  someotherfunctionsinside();
  if (e)...
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
});
```

and then calling

```
ajaxCartFormSubmitted(test);
```

But I get Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function. What is the problem? I use jquery 1.3 and cannot upgrade. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

### 1

There are two arguments `e` and `callback`.  You have to pass them both if you want the callback since that's your 2nd argument.

Like this: `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(event, test)`

You can't only pass the 2nd argument and skip the first one.  if you need to do this, write a different function.

### 2

if it gets called as `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(event, 'foo')` or `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(event, true)` then neither `'foo'` nor `true` are functions.  you just need to check that the type of `callback` is actually a function before you run it

```js
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, callback) {
  someotherfunctionsinside();
  if (e) {
    ...
  }
  if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback();
  }
});
```

if that's still not working, add a `console.log` in there so you can debug it and see what it is.

`console.log(typeof callback, callback)`

Comment: Thank you for response. I am getting undefined undefined in console. And the function test did not fire. However there are no errors. The (e) is probably an event - how can I pass it as a first argument?

Comment: *how can I pass [(e)] as a first arg?* - `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, test);`

Comment: Just pass something in there.  if you made the function you shoul dknow what goes in there.  it seems to have a check for `if(e) { ...` so if you want to skip it just pass `undefined` there, like this: `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(undefined, test)`

Answer (score 1):

> But I get Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function. What is the problem?

The problem is that you haven't passed `ajaxCartFormSubmitted` two arguments, you've only passed it one, which it receives as the parameter `e` (the first parameter). The `callback` parameter will be `undefined` when you do that.

Either pass it two arguments, or change the function so it only expects one.

What the function expects:

```
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, callback) {
//           First parameter --^  ^^^^^^^^--- second parameter
```

What you're sending it:

```
ajaxCartFormSubmitted(test);
//                    ^^^^------ First (only) argument
```