# callback returns Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

***Background info***

I am making an application which fetches data from the data via an AJAX call. If the success method meets the requirements, it calls a function and passes the callback parameter along as an argument. The callback gets invoked in a for loop then.

***Problem***

Whenever I invoke the callback function, it throws the error Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function (on line 39)

***Sources I have looked up and tried***

Let me start off by saying that I have already done a `console.log()` on the callback parameter and the value is correct.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

[Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099128/uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function)

[add callback to function(e) Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347115/add-callback-to-functione-uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function)

[Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099128/uncaught-typeerror-callback-is-not-a-function)

***My code***

```
function Query(eventObject, button, callback)
{
        //replaced not relevant code here with a comment.
        success: function(response) 
        {
            if (button === "getB")
            {
                //success fetches correctly. Already checked whether response could be empty. This is not the case
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if (callback)
                {
                    //pass the callback along
                    rollOut(response, callback);
                }
            }
        }
}
//THE FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO INVOKE
function setCheckboxes(valueToCompare)
{
    console.log(valueToCompare);
}

function rollOut(jsonResponse, callback)
{
    $(`.show-divSet`).on(`click`, function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++)
        {
            if (jsonResponse[i]["version"] !== "")
            {
                //CONSOLE SHOWS ME THE CORRECT VALUE
                console.log(callback);
                //THIS IS LINE 39. THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN
                callback(jsonResponse[i]["version"]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

***How I instantiate my code all***

```
$(function () {
    // I have already tried setCheckboxes WITHOUT quotes, but unfortunately this didn't work either
    Query("", "getB", "setCheckboxes");
});
```

Comment: `"setCheckboxes"` is a string not a callback, which is a function fyi

Comment: Try: `bibleQuery("", "getB", setCheckboxes);`. I guess this is a side effect of programming in PHP

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I would like to point out the comment above the "is a string not a callback". It still throws the same error, even without quotation marks.

Comment: Well, are you sure there exist a function called `setCheckboxes`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I kept the old name by accident. Thanks for pointing that out, made the edit so future people won't think i'm calling the wrong function. bibleQuery became Query. I made a wrong copy paste here (I had it originaly commented and took out the right function call when posting this). But your comment remains correct. Please feel free to edit the comment with "bibleQuery" to "Query", since it's a valid comment :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes. I made an edit for you to see. The function exists as far as i'm concerned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219563/discussion-between-i-try-so-hard-but-i-cry-harder-and-ibrahim-mahrir).

Comment: The code as is, is correct so I'm assuming the issue might be where you redacted the code. Can you share the whole code via jsbin.com or something like that?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah... You were right. Apparently calling the function as a string didn't do it, but without the quotation marks it worked. My question however would now be, why didn't this work in the first place? I am pretty sure I tried it a COUPLE OF TIMES without the quotation marks, but it would remain with the same error. I literally took it out after you said it as a desperate attempt and somehow it works now.

Comment: That may be because of a lot of reasons: you didn't save the changes, you didn't refresh, ... I can't tell. Maybe the development environment you are working with didn't update the changes in time for your testing of the code